# Laravel: inserting arrays to a table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5

I got this code where i can store all my result(**present,late,absent,others**) for each student.

**Here's my view**

```
 <div align="center"><b>List of Students Enrolled</b></div>
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
   <th>Student ID</th>
    <th>Student Name</th>
    <th>Present</th>
    <th>Late</th>
    <th>Absent</th>
    <th>Others</th>
    <th>Comments</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach ($users as $users)
            <tr>
      <td>{{ $users->student_id  }} </td>
       <td>{{ $users->student_firstname  }} {{ $users->student_lastname  }}</td> 
    <td>{{ Form::radio('student['.$users->student_id.'][status]', 'present' , true) }}</td>
<td>{{ Form::radio('student['.$users->student_id.'][status]', 'late' ) }}</td>
<td>{{ Form::radio('student['.$users->student_id.'][status]', 'absent') }}</td>
<td>{{ Form::radio('student['.$users->student_id.'][status]', 'others') }}</td>
<td>{{ Form::text('student['.$users->student_id.'][comment]') }}</td>





          @endforeach

            </tr>
      {{ HTML::script('js/bootstrap.js'); }}

    </tbody>

</table>
```

**Here's my controller where i save**

```
 foreach(Subject1::where('section_name', 'like', Input::get('section_name'))->where('code','like',Input::get('subject_code'))->get() as $student){



  foreach (Input::get('student') as $studentId ) {


                $attendance = new Attendances();
                $attendance->status = $studentId['status'];
                $attendance->comment =  $studentId['comment'];
               $attendance->student_id = $student->student_id;
                $attendance->student_firstname =  $student->student_firstname;
                $attendance->student_lastname =  $student->student_lastname;
                $attendance->teacher_id = Auth::user()->id;
                $attendance->teacher_firstname = Auth::user()->firstname;
                $attendance->teacher_lastname = Auth::user()->lastname;
                $attendance->section_id = $student->section_id;
                $attendance->section_name = Input::get('section_name');
                $attendance->subject_id = $student->id;
                $attendance->subject_code = $student->code;
                $attendance->subject_name = $student->name;
                $attendance->date_recorded = Input::get('date');
                $attendance->save();



}


}
```

However, when i saw the table in my database it shows two records where **student1 has a present and absent on the day itself as well as student2 (Assuming I input present on student1 and absent on student2**

Please help :(

Comment: Please update the question with the entire form code.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you loop through several students from input but also incorporate another student model from outside the loop. This is probably where your issue is.

Aside from that, you should probably only store the student id on the attendance table rather than all the student data like first/last name. Consider how mucked up things would be if someone has a name change.